# Eclipse won't start after upgrade; clean option not successful

Tags: android, eclipse

After trying to upgrade Eclipse components it won't start.

I needed to upgrade Android SDK, which needed an upgrade for AVD, which needed an upgrade of core Eclipse components.

After trying to upgrade core Eclipse components, Eclipse won't start.

After trying to start with -consoleLog -clean -data, I get the following output:

```
!SESSION 2014-06-01 15:02:24.722 -----------------------------------------------
eclipse.buildId=M20120208-0800
java.version=1.7.0_10
java.vendor=Oracle Corporation
BootLoader constants: OS=win32, ARCH=x86_64, WS=win32, NL=en_US
Framework arguments:  -data
Command-line arguments:  -os win32 -ws win32 -arch x86_64 -consoleLog -clean -da
ta

!ENTRY org.eclipse.osgi 4 0 2014-06-01 15:02:25.073
!MESSAGE The -clean (osgi.clean) option was not successful. Unable to clean the
storage area: C:\Program Files\Eclipse\configuration\org.eclipse.osgi
org.eclipse.m2e.logback.configuration: The org.eclipse.m2e.logback.configuration
bundle was activated before the state location was initialized.  Will retry aft
er the state location is initialized.
```

I've tried deleting workspace lock file (no snap files I could find), and this is as far as I can get.

I am running as Administrator on Win7.  No other answers with similar problems seem to have helped.

Stumped!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

as long as your workspace is separate , your risk of a complete reinstall is low.

1. download/reinstall  eclipse and hook it to your workspace
   start with 'clean' switch first time

Ok eclipse works now get the ADT/SDK for android and follow [instructions](http://developer.android.com/tools/sdk/eclipse-adt.html)

Ok now you should have android in there

Now upgrade is 2 separate steps

get cmdline in windose and run 'android'
   get the API levels you  need installed

after that restart eclipse, make sure you are connected to Android's update sites and check on the help menu 'check for upgrades' and run all thru that

you should be good

i dont use windows but the general list should help , regardless of OS.

as long as you did NOT corrupt Workspace and as long as your eclipse WS was at separate path in filesys, you are very safe with complete reinstall.

Comment: That is what I was afraid of, reinstall everything...  I LOVE rebuilding my workspace every time an upgrade is required.

Comment: if the WS was separate, no rebuild of that req'd. FWIW - i just did same thing on linux/Eclipse/ADT. If you have fast net connection , i don't think that it will take more than 45 min for entire thing??